# Transferring object through Pyro

Tags: python, distributed

I'm using Pyro in a project, and can't seem to understand how to transfer a complete object over the wire. The object is **not** distributed (my distributed objects works perfectly fine), but should function as an argument to an already available distributed object.

My object is a derived from a custom class containing some methods and some variables - an integer and a list. The class is available for both the server and the client. When using my object as an argument to a method of a distributed object the integer variable is "received" correctly, but the list is empty, even though I can see that it contains values just before it's "sent".

Why is this?

Short version of the class:

```
class Collection(Pyro.core.ObjBase):
    num = 0
    operations = [("Operation:", "Value:", "Description", "Timestamp")]

def __init__(self):
    Pyro.core.ObjBase.__init__(self)

def add(self, val, desc):
    entry = ("Add", val, desc, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    self.operations.append(entry)
    self.num = self.num + 1

def printop(self):
    print "This collection will execute the following operations:"
    for item in self.operations:
        print item
```

The receving method in the distributed object:

```
def apply(self, collection):
    print "Todo: Apply collection"
    #op = collection.getop()
    print "Number of collected operations:", collection.a
    collection.printop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operations is a class attribute, not the object attribute. That is why it's not transferred. Try setting it in `__init__` via `self.operations = <whatever>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your receiving method, **apply**, has the same name as the built-in Python function.